# How to get a blurry sphere boundary, to imitate a delocalized electron cloud?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, blur

I have a molecule which consists of atoms, electrons, and very thin lines connecting all possible particle combinations. I would like to make the electrons appear blurry, to illustrate the idea of delocalized particles (wave-particle duality, essentially).

I am using Eevee due to the sheer number of objects in my scene. I am not able to find a solution that works with eevee. How can I make a uv-sphere appear as a blurred?

[image]

### Desired effect

[Something like this](https://akvis.com/img/examples/lightshop/elements/blob-halo-75.jpg)

Comment: Volumetric material? Animate sphere as vibrating and use motion blur? Plane with spherical gradient faced to camera?

Comment: Can you link to resources or examples?

Comment: updated question. I guess a halo effect will suffice for my needs.

Comment: In Cycles, you'll need to do post processing. In Eevee, just enable bloom and give your object a bright emission material.

Comment: So you are looking for glowing spheres exactly as your reference or black sphere with white glow rim or black sphere fade on edges?

Comment: Emission with bloom achieves the effect to some extent, but the global setting also affects other objects where I would like less bloom. Also, the overall contrast is greatly reduced due the the bloom bleeding out. So a material solution would be the way to go for me, I think.

Answer (score 3):

### version Bloom

With simple Emission shader you can achieve that.
To eliminate blooming any other object in your scene

- set high shader *Emission* like 100
- and under *Render Properties > Bloom* set high *Threshold*  (here 10)

... so for other lights it would be hard or even impossible to reach bloom effect.

[image]

Play with other parameters to fine desired result ...

[image]

Since Eevee does not support mesh lights, those object doesn't light your scene so other objects stay untouched (until you use *Irradiance Volume* object).

You can't use bloom effect to color each "object" individually, since bloom color is set as general parametr per scene. You would have to separate objects in compositor or composite several scenes together ... that is not definitely efficient way.

### version Plane

In some cases you can cheat with old school method - Plane with gradient texture pointed to Camera.

- add Plane with *Gradient* texture as *Factor* for mixing *Emission* and *Transparency* node (don't forget to switch under *Material properties > Setting > Blend Mode > **Alpha Blend***).

[image]

- add *Constraint > **Damped Track** > Target - Camera* ... like that Plane is pointing face-normal directly to camera. So even Plane or Camera is moving plane stay orientated to camera ... it results in illusion you are watching sphere object.

[image]
[image]

As a tip ... if you close node tree into a NodeGroup you can easily share this setup in other materials and just change a color. Any other changes in setup inside the node group will stay synced in all materials.

Example in motion ...
[image]

It can be problematic with strings ... it really depend from case to case ... probably you can use also Gradient, but Linear to "fade" ends of strings like they are disappearing into blurred "sphere".

Comment: Can the bloom color be different for different objects?

Comment: Check edit ... I also wanted to share blend file, but I used experimental 3.1 that is not recognised by this site as blend file :) and also try to Append objects into official build is impossible ... so I hope description is clear for you.

Answer (score 0):

This simple setup should get you part of the way there.

[image]

You can use *Color Ramps* or *Math* -> *Multiply* (or lots of other) nodes to adjust the strength of these attributes.

[image]

Comment: So here you have a simple uv-sphere placed inside a cube, and the cube gets the volume material? I tried this, with exactly the same node setup, but I cannot reproduce the blur...

Comment: It works with cycles, but not eevee.

Comment: You're right, sorry.

Comment: @AlienSimpson ... why sorry in Eevee it works the same https://imgur.com/PaNF18N

Comment: ...I forgot that volumetrics aren't trash in Eevee anymore :D

I do not work in Eevee that much (only one major project so far!) so I really have no idea :)

Comment: @vklidu your answer is great, though

Comment: @Yoda ... There is not a Sphere just a Cube with Volumetric material ... what makes a blur spherical thing is Gradient 3D Texture > Spherical